# Wordpress: adding custom taxonomy in custom post type slug redirects other pages to homepage

Tags: wordpress, redirect, custom-post-type, slug, custom-taxonomy

I'm experiencing a problem with my custom post type: I set the slug to be *[www.example.com/taxonomy/posttype/postname](http://www.example.com/taxonomy/posttype/postname)*. But now other pages which don't have a parent page are automatically redirecting to the home page. If I change the order of the slug to *[www.example.com/posttype/taxonomy/postname](http://www.example.com/posttype/taxonomy/postname)*, there is no problem. But why?

To give some context: I got a site with a personal and professional environment. My pages are all */personal/info* or */professional/info*. I want my products to have slugs like */personal/product/productname* or */professional/product/productname*. If I now want to create a page which is intended for both environments (*/about-us*), this page redirects to the homepage.

Here is how I registered the post type & taxonomy:

```
register_post_type(
    'product',
    array(
        'label' => 'Product',
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => '%product_taxonomy%/product',
            'with_front' => true
        ),
    )
);

register_taxonomy(
    'product_taxonomy',
    'product',
    array(
        'label' => __('Taxonomy'),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'default_term' => array(
            'name' => __('Personal'),
            'slug' => __('personal')
        ),
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'product/product_taxonomy',
            'with_front' => false
        ),
    )
);
```

And this is the code to change the slug:

```
function filter_product_type_link( $link, $post ) {
    if( is_object( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'product' ) {
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'product_taxonomy' );
        if( $terms ) {   
            return str_replace( '%product_taxonomy%' , $terms[0]->slug , $link );
        }
    }
    return $link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'filter_product_type_link', 10, 2 );
```

After some research it looked like this was important to add, but I have no idea what it does:

```
function product_rewrite_rules( $rules ) {
    $terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_taxonomy',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ) );

    if( !empty( $terms ) ) {
        foreach( $terms as $term ) {
            add_rewrite_rule(
                '^' . $term->slug . '/(.*)/?$',
                'index.php?post_type=product&name=$matches[1]',
                'top'
            );
        }
    }
}
add_filter( 'init', 'product_rewrite_rules' );
```

After adding this code, my products do have the slug *[www.example.com/personal/product/productname](http://www.example.com/personal/product/productname)* (great!). The problem now is, that other pages (only pages which doesn't have a parent page) are being redirected to the homepage. Why?

Did anyone experience this issue before? I found some posts about this, but always where the posttype comes first in the slug.

Comment: Wordpress redirects to the home page or the link itself does not change, but the home page is shown ?

Comment: Wordpress redirects to the homepage, this is what I found in the Network tab: 

Request URL: http://www.example.com/about-us/ 
Request Method: GET 
Status Code: 301 Moved Permanently 
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:80 
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin 

And in the response headers: 
Location: http://www.example.com/